# Polish letters in HTML5 pattern

Tags: html

How to create a pattern in [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) with polish letters like ąęźżśóćńł?

I tried this:

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9ąęźżśóćńł]{4,31}$"
```

Comment: That should work. Is your HTML being served up with UTF-8 character encoding?

Comment: I'm assuming your question is "this doesn't work, and I want to know why". What input strings are not being validated, that you think should be?

Comment: @TedHopp I used UTF-8 character encoding in head section. `<meta charset="utf-8">`.   

@torazaburo It is not working and I want to have working solution - pattern with polish letters.

Comment: Having `<meta charset="uif-8">` in the header is good, but may not be enough. Have you verified that the response from the server is arriving with the pattern string properly encoded? In other words, is the server actually serving up UTF-8?

Comment: Yes it is. Without html pattern everything works correctly. I can register user with polish letters, and then sql base send it back correctly.
The problem must be in my pattern. It should be different I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I had wrong coding on my notepad++ . After change to utf8 everything works correctly.